# PHP header to download file causes string to change?

Tags: php, curl

I'm having an issue trying to download a string to a file via PHP.

```
$start = explode('-', Requests::param('start'));
        $end = explode('-', Requests::param('end'));

        $dates = array(
            'start' => array(
                'year' => intval($start[0]),
                'month' => intval($start[1]),
                'day' => intval($start[2])
            ),
            'end' => array(
                'year' => intval($end[0]),
                'month' => intval($end[1]),
                'day' => intval($end[2])
            )
        );

        $dates_json = json_encode($dates);

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($dates_json));
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dates_json);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="activities.csv"');
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($result));
        header('Connection: close');

        echo $result;
```

`$result` is a CSV file string.

It comes through the CURL request just fine, and if I don't have the headers and log it, it's just as it should be.

But as soon as I add the `header` functions, my `$result` string changes from the CSV file to just a single `"` and I have no clue why.

If I log it to my error file, it just logs as `1` instead of the `"` though, which is also strange.

The only other header that's set is `X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.20` so that shouldn't have any issue here.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:

- #### `CURLOPT_POST`

  > ```
  > $dates_json = json_encode($dates);
  > ...
  > curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($dates_json));
  > ```

  The [`CURLOPT_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) is a boolean option. You should set it to `TRUE` or `1`. Setting it to a count makes no sense.

  However, the result of [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) is a `string` (or `FALSE`). Applying [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) on something that is not an `array` or [`Countable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php) results in `1`, so it actually works in a roundabout way.
- #### `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`

  > ```
  > curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dates_json);
  > ```

  The [`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) option expects a urlencoded string or an associative array. You should pass something like:

  ```
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'dates=' . rawurlencode ($dates_json));
  ```

  or:

  ```
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array ('dates' => $dates_json));
  ```

  or (as an example):

  ```
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
    array ('start' => Requests::param('start'),
           'end'   => Requests::param('end')));
  ```

  or some other combination of keys and values depending on the target script. In the examples above, the script will have to retrieve the values using `$_POST['dates']`, or in the last example, `$_POST['start']` and `$_POST['end']`.
- #### `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`

  > ```
  > curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  >   'Content-Type: application/json'
  > ));
  > ```

  This makes no sense for a normal `POST` request. I think Curl will set the `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` depending on the form of value supplied to [`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).
- #### `curl_exec()`

  > ```
  > $result = curl_exec($ch);
  > ...
  > echo $result;
  > ```

  The default behaviour of [`curl_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) is to output the result directly, and return `TRUE` or `FALSE`. If `curl_exec()`  returns `TRUE`, the final `echo $result;` will output `1`.

  If you want `curl_exec()` to return the result instead of `TRUE`, you need to call `curl_setopt (CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1)`.

### SUMMARY

To summarize, you code might look *something* like this, depending on what parameters your target `$url` expects:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'dates=' . rawurlencode ($dates_json));

if (!curl_exec($ch)) {
  // Error message
}
curl_close($ch);
```